# Unexpected results when reusing a custom object for the pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, psobject, new-object

A while ago I changed my [`Join-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) cmdlet which appeared to cause a bug which didn’t reveal in any of my testing.
The objective of the change was mainly code minimizing and trying to improve performance by preparing a custom PSObject and reusing this in the pipeline.
As the [`Join-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) cmdlet is rather complex, I have created a simplified cmdlet to show the specific issue:
<sub>(The PowerShell version is: `5.1.16299.248`)</sub>

```
Function Test($Count) {
    $PSObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name = $Null; Value = $Null}
    For ($i = 1; $i -le $Count; $i++) {
        $PSObject.Name = "Name$i"; $PSObject.Value = $i
        $PSObject
    }
}
```

Directly testing the output gives exactly what I expected:

```
Test 3 | ft

Value Name
----- ----
    1 Name1
    2 Name2
    3 Name3
```

Presuming that it shouldn't matter whether I assign the result to a variable (e.g. `$a`) or not, but it does:

```
$a = Test 3
$a | ft

Value Name
----- ----
    3 Name3
    3 Name3
    3 Name3
```

So, apart from sharing this experience, I wonder whether this is programming flaw or a PowerShell bug/quirk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original approach is indeed conceptually flawed in that **you're outputting the *same* object multiple times, iteratively modifying its properties**.

The **discrepancy in output** is **explained** by the pipeline's item-by-item processing:

- *Outputting to the console* (via `ft` / `Format-Table`) prints the *then-current* state of `$PSObject` in each iteration, which gives the appearance that everything is fine.
- *Capturing in a variable*, by contrast, reflects `$PSObject`'s state *after all iterations* have completed, at which point it contains only the *last* iteration's values, `Name3` and `3`.

---

You can verify that output array `$a` indeed references the very same custom object three times as follows:

```
[object]::ReferenceEquals($a[0], $a[1]) # $True
[object]::ReferenceEquals($a[1], $a[2]) # $True
```

---

The solution is therefore to **create a distinct `[pscustomobject]` instance in *each iteration***:

**PSv3+** offers syntactic sugar for creating custom objects: you can cast a hashtable (literal) to `[pscustomobject]`. Since this also creates a new instance every time, you can use it to simplify your function:

```
Function Test($Count) {
  For ($i = 1; $i -le $Count; $i++) {
    [pscustomobject] @{ Name = "Name$i"; Value = $i  }
  }
}
```

Here's your own **PSv2-compatible solution**:

```
Function Test($Count) {
    $Properties = @{}
    For ($i = 1; $i -le $Count; $i++) {
        $Properties.Name = "Name$i"; $Properties.Value = $i
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }
}
```